# Looping across rows without 'for'

Tags: r, loops

I have a dataframe:

```
set.seed(1)
My_DF <- cbind(paste0("Project",1:10),rnorm(10))
colnames(My_DF) <- c( "Projeck_Name","Values")
My_DF



     Projeck_Name Values              
 [1,] "Project1"   "-0.626453810742332"
 [2,] "Project2"   "0.183643324222082" 
 [3,] "Project3"   "-0.835628612410047"
 [4,] "Project4"   "1.59528080213779"  
 [5,] "Project5"   "0.329507771815361" 
 [6,] "Project6"   "-0.820468384118015"
 [7,] "Project7"   "0.487429052428485" 
 [8,] "Project8"   "0.738324705129217" 
 [9,] "Project9"   "0.575781351653492" 
[10,] "Project10"  "-0.305388387156356"
```

and I want to assign the column two as a value for variable in column one. In other words Project1 will be a variable which contains a value `"-0.62645"`:

```
assign(My_DF[1,1],My_DF[1,2])
```

I want to perform this for all the Projects:

```
for(i in 1:length(My_DF[,1])) {
  assign(My_DF[i,1],My_DF[i,2])
}
```

Is there a way to do it without a 'for' loop in an efficient way?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I doubt use of `apply` with be much more efficient

Comment: Ok Will change the title

Comment: Perhaps something like this works for you `rownames(My_DF) = My_DF[,1]; My_DF = My_DF[,-1];My_DF["Project2"]` An approximate solution.

Comment: Note that example "dataframe" you provided is not a dataframe, it is a matrix. Check `class(My_DF)`. Maybe try this to make it a dataframe  `My_DF <- data.frame(Projeck_Name = paste0("Project",1:10), Values = rnorm(10))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will create 10 new variables `Project1`, `Project2` etc..

```
txt <- paste(df$Project_Name, "<-", df$Values, sep="")
eval(parse(text=txt))

Project1
[1] -0.6264538
Project2
[1] 0.1836433
```

**Sample data:**

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(Project_Name=paste0("Project",1:10), Values=rnorm(10))
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making 10 objects in the workspace, keep them in a named *list*.

```
# example dataframe
set.seed(1); My_DF <- data.frame(Projeck_Name = paste0("Project",1:10), Values = rnorm(10))

# keep each project value in a list
allProjects <- as.list(setNames(My_DF$Values, My_DF$Projeck_Name))

allProjects$Project1
# [1] -0.6264538
```

Comment: Thank you! I will consider it in the future.